# Loading 3rd party dlls for common use in Visual Studio 2012, C++

Tags: dll

I have glut32.dll file which needs to be in the Debug folder whenever I compile a source. It's very frustrating to manually put in the Debug folder of each project file to have it run properly.

Is it possible I can put it in some folder and point the project to it?

I am a newbie with Visual Studio 2012.

Before this question being tagged as a duplicate, I want to add I keep seeing suggestions Referencing third party dlls, but I couldn't get it. 
Any help appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

If you add a project reference to this DLL, I believe it should be copied to the Debug folder automatically.

Comment: I have a lot of projects, is it possible to put it one place for all the projects to use?

Comment: You *might* be able to get away with putting it in the default Windows PATH and have it still run (e.g. C:\Windows\System32\). However, if you ever distribute the App, you'll need to make sure that glut32.dll is included.